# ¿Por qué no puedo comparar DateTime is null en C# y sí DateTime == null?

Tags: c#, datetime, estructuras

Estaba trabajando en una aplicación en C# (aprendido sobre la marcha en mi puesto de trabajo, pero sin un conocimiento profundo del lenguaje) cuando me topé con algo que llamó mi atención: puedo realizar una comparación de un `DateTime` con un nulo mediante el operador de igualdad `operator==`, pero no mediante el operador `is` (Error CS0037).

La pregunta que me surgió inmediatamente es: *¿Por qué es esto posible? ¿Por qué puedo realizar tal comparación con un operador y con el otro no? ¿Es realmente necesaria dicha comprobación?*

La duda no es si se puede comparar o no, sino por qué se puede de una manera y no de otra.

Después de investigar un poco, encontré una solución, que agrego como respuesta para quien le interese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las clases en C# son *tipos referencia*, es decir, sus instancias (los objetos) son referencias (o punteros) a zonas de memoria montón, o *heap*, que contienen información en sus campos: valores u otras referencias. Además, como referencias que son, pueden compararse con la *referencia nula* (`null`), que viene a representar al objeto inválido, o el que todavía no ha sido creado (valor entero 0, puntero 0x0..0).

Por otro lado, las estructuras son *tipos valor*, es decir, no son referencias a zonas de memoria que contienen información, sino información en sí misma, sin el nivel de indirección de las referencias. Al declararlas (y usarlas), van a ocupar espacio en la pila, o *stack*.

Sabiendo esto, la respuesta corta es que no se puede comparar estructuras (`struct`) con la referencia nula (`null`) porque las estructuras no son referencias a valores, sino valores en sí mismos. Dicho de otro modo: no existen las estructuras nulas.

Ahora bien, C# permite declarar variables de tipos valor que aceptan nulos mediante los llamados *tipos nulables*, que son versiones genéricas de los tipos originales (o mejor dicho clases genéricas donde el tipo parametrizado es un tipo valor). Estos tipos nulables aceptan valores nulos, y sus variables se declaran añadiendo una interrogación tras el tipo valor de la variable (por ejemplo, `int?` es el tipo nulable correspondiente al tipo valor `int`). Y aunque en código lo escribamos de manera simplificada, la definición real de los nulables que podemos encontrar en la documentación es: `Nullable<T> where T : struct`, por lo que `DateTime?` equivale a `Nullable<DateTime>`.

En estas condiciones, sí podemos comparar un tipo valor con su correspondiente nulable, mediante el operador de igualdad (`==`), teniendo en cuenta que un tipo nulable nunca será igual a una variable de tipo valor si el nulable es nulo.

```
int enteroNormal = 3;
int? enteroNulableValor = 3;
int? enteroNulableNulo = null;

if (enteroNormal == enteroNulableValor) ;    // true
if (enteroNormal == enteroNulableNulo) ;     // false
if (3 == null) ;                             // false
```

Así, internamente, comparar un tipo valor con su correspondiente nulable es similar a lo siguiente:

```
Estructura estructura = new Estructura();
Estructura? nulable = /* ... */;

bool igualdad = nulable.HasValue && estructura == nulable.Value;
```

Como se observa, la condición de igualdad comprueba primero si el nulable tiene valor (lo que equivale a no ser nulo), y más tarde se aplica el operador de igualdad sobre el valor almacenado en el nulable, que es del tipo valor correspondiente, que en el ejemplo es de tipo `Estructura`.

Por tanto, comparar una estructura con un nulo implica la obligación de implementar el operador de igualdad en el tipo valor, es decir en el `struct`.

Así, una expresión como `(estructura == null)` se evalúa como falsa porque:

- Primero se toma `null` como una variable de tipo `Estructura?`, la versión nulable de `Estructura`, es decir, `Nullable<Estructura>`.
- Más tarde se realiza la comprobación arriba indicada.
- Como el nulable es nulo, no tiene un valor de tipo `Estructura`, por lo que la expresión evalúa a falso sin aplicar el operador de igualdad re definido en `Estructura`, ya que `&&` es un operador cortocircuito.

Ejemplo de código en [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

Finalmente, la respuesta es sencilla: mediante el operador de igualdad, se está comparando la estructura `DateTime` con su respectivo nulable asignado a `null`, lo que siempre evalúa a falso. El compilador lo sabe, y realiza optimizaciones para no hacer dicha comprobación, por lo que no se genera código ejecutable para esa condición.

Ahora bien, el operador `is` realiza una comprobación de tipos primero, y al ser de tipos distintos (`DateTime` y `DateTime?`, o mejor dicho, `Nullable<DateTime>`), no permite ni siquiera que el programa compile.